# How to observe LiveData<PagedList> with android paging in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-livedata, android-paging

I can't observe the `LiveData<PagedList>` change in activity, but the UI is updated(the list has grown in activty).

I can only observe it once when the livedata is initialized.
when the paging library call loadAfter method, the ui is updated, but didn't call pageList.observe{}

Firstly, I put the process of data request into the Kotlin Coroutines, I can't observe the data change, then I used asynchronous requests instead.It still didn't work.

Here is my code:

PlayActivity main code

```
private val commentAdapter =
        object : BasePagedAdapter(diffCallback, this) {
            // just bind recycleview item and corresponding view model. etc.
        }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_play)
        binding.vm = vm
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        val workId = intent.getLongExtra(WORK_ID, 0)

        vm.listComment(workId)

        play_rv_comment.adapter = commentAdapter

        /* herer is the problem*/
        vm.commentList.observe(this, Observer {
            /*only log once when called loadInitial*/
            LogUtils.e("observe", it)
            commentAdapter.submitList(it)
        })
```

PlayViewModel

```
class PlayViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    var workId: Long = 0
    // the data which I want to observe
    lateinit var commentList: LiveData<PagedList<WorkComment>>

    private val commentPageSize = 15

    fun listComment(workId: Long) {
        // init by DataSource.Factory in android paging library
        commentList = BaseDataSourceFactory(workId).toLiveData(commentPageSize)

    }
```

DataSource.Factory in Android paging

```
class BaseDataSourceFactory(
    val workId: Long
) :
    DataSource.Factory<Long, WorkComment>() {

    override fun create(): DataSource<Long, WorkComment> {
        return object : PageKeyedDataSource<Long, WorkComment>() {
            override fun loadInitial(
                params: LoadInitialParams<Long>,
                callback: LoadInitialCallback<Long, WorkComment>
            ) {
                try {
                    val res = RetrofitUtil.getInstanceWithJwt().create(WorkCommentApi::class.java)
                        .listComment(
                            workId, 1, params.requestedLoadSize
                        )
                    res.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<TResult> {
                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<TResult>, t: Throwable) {
                        }

                        override fun onResponse(call: Call<TResult>, response: Response<TResult>) {
                            callback.onResult(
                                response.body()!!.toList(WorkComment::class.java),
                                null, 2)
                        }
                    })
                } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
                    ToastUtils.showShort("请稍候重试")
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    LogUtils.e(e.localizedMessage)
                }

            }

            // called many times, but I can't observe the PagedList change
            override fun loadAfter(
                params: LoadParams<Long>,
                callback: LoadCallback<Long, WorkComment>
            ) {
                val res = RetrofitUtil.getInstanceWithJwt().create(WorkCommentApi::class.java)
                    .listComment(
                        workId, 1, params.requestedLoadSize
                    )
                res.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<TResult> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<TResult>, t: Throwable) {
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<TResult>, response: Response<TResult>) {
                        callback.onResult(
                            response.body()!!.toList(WorkComment::class.java),
                            params.key + 1
                        )
                    }
                })
            }

            override fun loadBefore(
                params: LoadParams<Long>,
                callback: LoadCallback<Long, WorkComment>
            ) {
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Retrofit Api

```
interface WorkCommentApi {

    /**
     * list comment
     */
    @GET("public/work/comment")
    fun listComment(@Query("workId") workId: Long, @Query("current") current: Long, @Query("size") size: Int): Call<TResult>
}
```

I want to know what should I do to observe the `LiveData<PagedList>` change

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because each time you call `vm.listComment(workId)`, the object you first bound in activity is killed and new object is created.

You can use `Transformations` with `MediatorLiveData`.

Activity:

```
 viewModel.logout().observe(this, Observer { 
// do here
})
```

ViewModel:

```
class RepackViewModel(app: Application) : BaseViewModel(app) {

// IMPORTANT - Mediator
    val logout = MediatorLiveData<PagedList<WorkComment>>()
    fun logout() : LiveData<PagedList<WorkComment>> = logout
   init {
// IMPORTANT - passes repo update to activity 
       logout.addSource(repo.getLogoutResponse()) { logout.postValue(it) }
  }
}
```

Repository:

```
class BaseRepository(val app: Application) {

    private val logout = MutableLiveData<PagedList<WorkComment>>()

    fun getLogoutResponse(): LiveData<PagedList<WorkComment>> = logout

   override fun create(): DataSource<Long, WorkComment> {
  //when you get your data
   logout.value = // your value
}
```

Comment: I just called `vm.listComment(workId)` once when activity is created, Was it created twice or more times?

Comment: No.. but i had faced a similar issue, n MediatorLiveData solved the problem. So you can try this approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your work id be mutable data to be observed by the transformation.  so whenever you update your work, id, it will fetch comments. Like Thus...

> ViewModel:

```
val workIdMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(workId)

//This performs the meat of the work to display the items in the recyclerview
var commentsList = Transformations.switchMap(workIdMutableLiveData) { workId ->
    val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPageSize(pagingLimit)
        .build()
    val pagedListBuilder = LivePagedListBuilder<Long, WorkComment>(BaseDataSourceFactory(workId), config)
    pagedListBuilder.build()
}
```

> Then in your activity, observe

```
    yourViewModel.commentsList.observe(this, Observer { list ->
        list ?: return@Observer

        adapter.submitList(list)
        yourRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    })
```

Whenever you update the workIdMutableLiveData by doing a

```
workIdMutableLiveData.postValue(workId)
```

...The recyclerview will update.  Your recyclerview must inherit from PagedListAdapter.

Comment: the workId is a constant that doesn't change in this activity, do you have another way? I don't know why I can't observe the commentList

Comment: How does your comment list change? Your data source is updating the comment list.  Work id is what is generating the comments.

Answer (score 0):

After testing, I knew list couldn't be observed when it has inner data change, like `add()`, `remove()`. etc.

It only be observed when its reference has been changed, like create or assignment operation: 
`list.value = null`

So I couldn't observe the data change of `LiveData<List>`